# how to secure flash file from being downloaded or extracted in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, flash, security

I'm asked to develop a secured flash viewer in C# (WinForm) where flash files will be viewable through the viewer however being securely captured within the viewer - i.e. make it not extractable nor downloadable by any sniffer tools.

I haven't got a good solution for this yet, any one help?

Comment: Are you downloading the flash files from a web service to play them?

Comment: No I'm not sure how to create the application yet - it is supposed to be winForm application so I'd imagine there'll be a control used similar to webbroser control that can open the flash file?  (The file is from local and encrypted, and will be decrypted when using it in the viewer)

Comment: Thsi is not possible. In the most complicated case the user will just record the screen as the video is being played.

Comment: Considering the code for decryption will be in your software I don't see why someone cant't just reverse engineer your application, retrieve the decryption code then just create an application that just dumps the stream on the disk as a file.

Comment: The file is deciphered and run locally, you cannot prevent extracting it. You can make it harder, but you can't prevent it.

Comment: Well there's nothing you can really do to prevent someone from breaking open your application, getting the private keys, and decrypting the flash files. The obfuscation of the program would help, but it's not fool proof. The flash files would need to be streamed from a service for any lasting security.

Comment: @Romoku, even if the files are streamed you can get them. As long as they run on a computer, this computer can write its memory to a file on a local drive...

Comment: It's horrible to work for a retarded employer :) "Secure" and "Flash" don't go well together, encrypting something only to decrypt and pass it to Flash player - obviously useless. WinForm + Flash - both outdated tech... I don't envy your task at all

Comment: in fact the decryption key will be obtained from a service so relatively better than streaming the file back to local drive (also solving the lasting security problem)

Comment: The key does end up on the users computer at the end. The key concept is, if the computer can do it, so can the user. So if the computer can decrypt the file and play it, the user can do the same but instead of playing just dumping it as a file.

Comment: @Guillaume The point I was trying to illustrate is security only comes  in degrees and it is increased by minimizing the information footprint on the hostile environment at any moment.

Comment: The only thing that retrieving a key from a service solves is that the one that will be cracking the application will require a valid licence before creating the dumping software (usually a stolen one from another user). There are measures that you can take against it, making sure only one user is logged at the time with the credentials and so on but the real question is, how much of the user experience are you willing to give away in order to increase the softwares security ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will make this in a form of an answer to stop bombarding the comment section.

The task you have at hand will be extremely difficult if you don't want to make your application very user unfriendly.

The reason for that is because if your program can decrypt the information locally then play the video file then a skilled user in reversed engineering can access the method of decryption and use it to dump the video as a file.

Now in case you want to make a licence method and have the users log in before they can use the program you will have two issues.

1) It will still be possible for a person that wants to crack the program to do so, the only thing he/she will need is a valid licence in this case, which in most cases they are stolen from other users. Something that is hard to notice server side except if you have someone constantly looking at the logs banning licences and handling the calls of the users that will be calling because their (stolen) licence is no longer working.

2) Put some kind of limitations server wide as to how many people can login with the credentials which will create more issues, people won't be able to use the software on two pcs at the same time for example. Even the problem above will still be an issue but users will complain why they can't login this time (since someone else will be using their licence.

Moral of the story ? There is always a way around things. Depends how much user experience you are willing to throw away in order to make your software just a bit more safer from being cracked.

Comment: I totally agreed - argued with other team members and decided to try the best security we can with all user experience requirements met based on customer's request.  there'll be never an absolute answer on how to "secure" something...

Comment: That is the best thing in my opinion as well. Big known companies have been trying to deal with this subject for a lot of years now and after so many years the "solution" they found to work decently  (something that is not possible to compliment in this case) is to move the logic code on the server side, which does work decently against piracy quite good, but the amount of legit users that have to suffer from this is quite high. From servers not been able to handle the requests to just people ddosing their servers down just to annoy people, rendering the product pretty much unusable.

Comment: Not to mention as Eugene Mayevski mentioned in the comments, worst case scenario in this case you will just record the window that will show the video and just crop it in a video editing software, and tada you have the video in a file. A technique that I don't think there is a solution for at this point. If it was possible to make videos secure from being downloaded the first ones that would have found a solution would be Youtube :)